# Is the security.SE blog still alive or not? Is BlogOverflow itself dead?

Tags: support, blog

It looks like there is a Security blog with [great articles](https://security.blogoverflow.com/2011/11/why-passwords-should-be-hashed/), but it has a banner at the top that says it is an archive. When you click on the banner, however, the [About page](https://security.blogoverflow.com/about/) it leads to has nothing to that effect and looks like the site is still up. But there is also a box in the upper right that links to http://blogoverflow.com, which redirects to an error page.

So what is the deal with Schrodinger's blog here? Is it alive or not?

Answer (score 4):

> the About page it leads to has nothing to that effect and looks like the site is still up.

Because it's an archival copy of the About page that existed when the blog was active. The banner on top is present on the About page, and indicates its archival status.

Indeed, the existing links to http://blogoverflow.com/ redirect to https://stackexchange.com/blogs which shows Page Not Found.  A more specific error page may have been better, but the behavior is valid, as the site no longer exists.

There were plans for a new blog, completely separate from the previous instance. See

- [Do we want to continue with our blog?](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2515/do-we-want-to-continue-with-our-blog?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [New blog - call for volunteers](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2553/new-blog-call-for-volunteers?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [Blog - actions required](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2587/blog-actions-required?noredirect=1&lq=1)

The upshot is: there was some vague interest, but nobody put in the time and energy required to make it happen.

Comment: then why the heck does that banner link to a page that doesn't provide more explanation of what the banner talks about?

Comment: also, it would be nice to have the banner (or the page it links to) provide a link to a meta post or even blog post (oh the irony) of why blogoverflow is shutting down.